# VirtualMin Installation error for Updated PHP 7 environment in CentOS

Tags: php, centos, dependencies, virtualmin

I have recently updated my server’s PHP from 5.4.xx to 7. After that I tried to install VirtualMin in my server, which lead me to the following error:

```
▣▣□ Phase 2 of 3: Installation
Downloading epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm                            [  ✔  ]
Installing EPEL release package                                         [  ✔  ]
Installing yum-utils                                                    [  ✔  ]
Enabling extras repository                                              [  ✔  ]
Installing scl-utils                                                    [  ✔  ]
Install Software Collections release package                            [  ✔  ]
Installing PHP7                                                         [  ✔  ]
Marking 'Virtualmin LAMP Stack' for install                             [  ✔  ]
Marking 'Virtualmin Core' for install                                   [  ✔  ]
Installing dependencies and system packages                             [ERROR] Failed with error: 1
[  ✘  ]

[ERROR] Something went wrong. Exiting.
[ERROR] The last few log entries were:
Spin pid is: 15710
Error: php70u-mysqlnd conflicts with php-mysql-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: php-mysql conflicts with php70u-mysqlnd-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
Error: php70u-xml conflicts with php-xml-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: php70u-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: php70u-gd conflicts with php-gd-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: mod_php70u conflicts with php-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: php70u-pdo conflicts with php-pdo-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
webmin-1.881-1.noarch has missing requires of perl(Encode::Detect)
Installing dependencies and system packages: [2018-04-12 15:39:46 +06] [ERROR] Failed with error: 1
[2018-04-12 15:39:46 +06] [ERROR] Something went wrong. Exiting.
[2018-04-12 15:39:46 +06] [ERROR] The last few log entries were:
```

For your information: WebMin is already installed in my server and running fine, and other websites hosted in this server are running fine too.

Some output from my server that might be helpful:

```
aa@xx bin]# rpm -qa | grep php
php70-php-mysqlnd-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-json-post-1.0.1-3.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-opcache-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
rh-php70-php-json-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-mysqlnd-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-pspell-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
php70-php-cli-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-devel-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pspell-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-cli-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70u-gd-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-cli-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-devel-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-fpm-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
php70-runtime-1.0-5.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-1.0-5.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-8.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-xmldiff-1.1.2-6.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-memcache-3.0.9-0.9.20170802.e702b5f.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-xmlrpc-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-pdo-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70u-devel-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
mod_php70u-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-common-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-pear-1.10.1-3.el7.noarch
rh-php70-php-xmlrpc-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-gd-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
php70-php-json-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pdo-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-process-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-gd-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pear-1.10.5-5.el7.remi.noarch
php70-php-mbstring-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-tidy-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-common-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70u-opcache-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-zip-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-process-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-2.3-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-opcache-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-bcmath-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
php70-php-common-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-zip-1.15.2-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-apcu-5.1.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-mysqlnd-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-xml-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-mbstring-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64
php70-php-xml-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-pecl-geoip-1.1.1-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70-php-soap-7.0.29-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php70u-xml-7.0.28-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
rh-php70-runtime-2.3-1.el7.x86_64
rh-php70-php-pdo-7.0.10-2.el7.x86_64

aa@xx ~]# php -v
PHP 7.0.28 (cli) (built: Mar  1 2018 10:03:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.28, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Now I am stuck in here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Virtualmin *install.sh* script, which is recommended to be run on the fresh server.

For your case, you need to solve dependency problems for PHP and then re-run the install script.